# How to backup a content database with Backup-SPFarm cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, backup

According to [official KB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/back-up-a-content-database), the cmdlet should be

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory <BackupFolder> -BackupMethod {Full | Differential} -Item <ContentDatabaseName> [-Verbose]
```

However when I run above cmdlet on SP2016 on-premise, it warn me as below:

```
Run again with either:
        Farm\Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application\SharePoint - 80\WSS_Content
        Farm\Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application\SharePoint - 80\WSS_Content_2018
        Farm\Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application\SharePoint - 80\WSS_Content_2019
```

Although the warning is very clear that I need to change my cmdlet's "-item" parameter, it is not aligned with official article. Anyway, I tried run again with `-item "Farm\Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application\SharePoint - 80\WSS_Content"`. The backup started and ended with error:

> [FatalError] Object WSS_Content failed in event OnBackup. For more
> information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the
> backup directory.     SqlException: Cannot open backup device
> 'd:\backup\spbr0000\000000DF.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system
> cannot find the path specified.). BACKUP DATABASE is terminating
> abnormally.

Is the MS article still valid?

I ran the cmdlet at my APP server with my farm admin account. It looks like the powershell is trying to carry out SQL backup at SQL server. How should I tune my cmdlet and what permission I need to grant between APP and SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the article is valid, the issue is the destination used. If SQL Server is not on the same server as SharePoint, you must use a UNC path (\\serverName\shareName) granting the SQL Server service account with Share permissions of Full Control and NTFS permissions of Modify.

I would instead suggest using a SQL Server Agent job to perform the backup.

Comment: The article mentioned `-Item <ContentDatabaseName>` but actually I need to type in entire path `-item "Farm\Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application\SharePoint - 80\WSS_Content"`. Is it my environment or the article invalid?